# How can I set "organize imports" to put each import on a new line

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Instead of having imports from the same package on the same line I would like each import to be on a separate line to avoid merge conflicts. When I press <kbd>Shift + Alt + O</kbd> however, it puts all the imports on the same line between brackets. Is there a way to customise this shortcut so that it puts each import on a separate line?

e.g. instead of having

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple, Union
```

I would like to have

```
from typing import Dict
from typing import List
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, Organize Imports for python uses `isort`. By looking at [isort's command line arguments,](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/multi_line_output_modes.html) we see that you can achieve this functionality by adding the following arguments:

```sh
--multi-line 7 --sl
```

With that said, you can go to your settings, search for `Python > Sort Imports: Args`, and add the following:

[image: Sort Imports Args]

Or you can manually add the entry in `settings.json`:

```json
"python.sortImports.args": [
  "--multi-line",
  "7",
  "--sl"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`isort --sl .` This should be enough.

```
  --sl, --force-single-line-imports
                        Forces all from imports to appear on their own line
```